# Return data entered in column order by row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am working on a simple timesheet module for a larger production system and need to display a table of information to the user.  I have the following tables to work with:

```
TimeRecords
  ID
  WorkerID
  AssyLineID
  Station
  Sequence
  NbrHours
  DateSubmitted

Workers
  ID
  Name

AssyLines
  Name
```

During data entry, time is entered by AssyLine for each worker.  A given worker may work on 2 or more different stations during the course of the day.  The Sequence value is assigned based on the order of names as entered during data entry.

Now I want to return this data for all assembly lines and all workers in the following format:

```
ResultSet
  Worker.ID
  Worker.Name
  AssyLine.Name  - group returned rows by assembly line, in alphabetical order
  Sequence       - within each assembly line, group by sequence
  NbrHours       - total hours for worker for this assembly line, all stations
  TotalHours     - total hours for this worker across all assembly lines and stations
```

Other caveats:
1) The rows for a given worker should be grouped together, starting with the assembly line where they logged the most hours, in the sequence for that assembly line. I plan to consolidate all entries for a given worker into one row for display to the user and this is much easier if all rows for one user are grouped together.  If that can't be done I will have to group and sort the row data in code...

Here is the query I have come up with so far:

```
 SELECT
         w.ID
        ,w.Name
        ,a.Name
        ,tr.NbrHours
        ,tr.Seq
    FROM
        TimeRecords tr
            INNER JOIN
        Workers w ON
          w.ID = tr.WorkerId
            INNER JOIN
        AssyLines a ON
          a.AssyLineID = tr.AssyLineId
    WHERE
        tr.DateSubmitted < '2000-01-01'
    ORDER BY
         w.Name
        ,a.Name
        ,tr.Seq
        ,NbrHours DESC
```

Obviously this leaves a lot to be desired.  The worker entries are not grouped together and there is no overall total for the worker.

Can anyone help me get this right? I'm thinking I will need to do this with a Stored Proc rather than a view...

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 1):

Most of this can be done with a simple group by clause; the messy part comes with your requirement for showing all hours, but I believe something like this should work depending on what DB you are using:

```
SELECT
     w.ID
    ,w.Name
    ,a.Name
    ,tr.Seq
    ,SUM(tr.NbrHours) as nbrHours
    (SELECT SUM(tr.NbrHours) 
       FROM TimeRecords tr2 
      WHERE tr2.WorkerId = w.id and tr2..DateSubmitted < '2000-01-01') as TotalHours
FROM
    TimeRecords tr
        INNER JOIN
    Workers w ON
      w.ID = tr.WorkerId
        INNER JOIN
    AssyLines a ON
      a.AssyLineID = tr.AssyLineId
WHERE
    tr.DateSubmitted < '2000-01-01'
GROUP BY
     w.ID
    ,w.Name
    ,a.Name
    ,tr.Seq
ORDER BY
     ReportName
    ,ShortName
    ,tr.Seq
```

Comment: That doesn't quite get me where I need to be -- the only thing it gains me is the total hours across all lines, and I thank you for that.  However, it doesn't meet the caveat I added, then rewrote to make more sense - this data is destined for a report in assembly line order first with only one row per worker containing all hours worked.  I also need that row to appear with the assembly line where they logged the most hours.

Comment: In the end I went with something very similar to this, without the ORDER BY clause - it does nothing for a view, as far as I can tell.  I then did the ordering in a Linq query to create a collection and looped through the collection to group the employee hours together into a list of records with embedded lists of hours and assembly lines.  I can't credit this as an answer as there doesn't appear to be an answer to the question I asked...  sorry.